# issue with regexp with nested groups in golang

Tags: regex, go, re2

Consider the following toy example. I want to match in Go a name with a regexp where the name is sequences of letters `a` separated by single `#`, so `a#a#aaa` is valid, but `a#` or `a##a` are not. I can code the regexp in the following two ways:

```
r1 := regexp.MustCompile(`^a+(#a+)*$`)
r2 := regexp.MustCompile(`^(a+#)*a+$`)
```

Both of these work. Now consider more complex task of matching a sequence of names separated by single slash. As in above, I can code that in two ways:

```
^N+(/N+)*$
^(N+/)*N+$
```

where N is a regexp for the name with ^ and $ stripped. As I have two cases for N, so now I can have 4 regexps:

```
    ^a+(#a+)*(/a+(#a+)*)*$
    ^(a+#)*a+(/a+(#a+)*)*$
    ^((a+#)*a+/)*a+(#a+)*$
    ^((a+#)*a+/)*(a+#)*a+$
```

The question is why when matching against the string `"aa#a#a/a#a/a"` the first one fails while the rest 3 cases work as expected? I.e. what causes the first regexp to mismatch? The full [code](http://play.golang.org/p/tJFwK-RUKq) is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "aa#a#a/a#a/a"
    regs := []string {
        `^a+(#a+)*(/a+(#a+)*)*$`,
        `^(a+#)*a+(/a+(#a+)*)*$`,
        `^((a+#)*a+/)*a+(#a+)*$`,
        `^((a+#)*a+/)*(a+#)*a+$`,
    }    
    for _, r := range(regs) {
        fmt.Println(regexp.MustCompile(r).MatchString(str))
    } 
}
```

Surprisingly it prints `false true true true`

Comment: `^a+(\#a+)*(/a+(\#a+)*)*$` matches `aa#a#a/a#a/a`

Comment: Yes, they all match. https://regex101.com/r/zA1sV0/1

Comment: @JamesBuck, but https://play.golang.org/p/7ZBXlug-66

Comment: @JamesBuck Not sure how that helps. The question is about Go, not PHP.

Comment: That's the really the nice one. Similarly, "^1(2(_1+)*)*$" does not match "12_1" but "^1(2(_1+)*)+$" does!

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Yes that is weird, must be something strange with the Go regex engine. All of the other regex engines I tried match this pattern against the string.

Comment: The regex works when changing the last quantifier to 1 or more rather than 0 or more - `^a+(#a+)*(/a+(#a+)*)+$`. Not sure why.

Comment: @JamesBuck , I agree, that really strange.

Comment: Maybe a bug in RE2? I've [twitted](https://twitter.com/alex_at_net/status/625793785096749056) and added [re2] in tags. Maybe it makes sense to report this issue to RE2 issue tracker as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to alleviate atomic sub-nesting of quantifiers.
If you didn't have the anchors, the expression would possibly blow up
in backtracking if using nested optional quantifiers like this,
when it can't find a direct solution.

Go might be balking at that, forcing it to fail outright instead
of massive backtracking, but not sure.

Try something like this, see if it works.

```
 # ^a+(#?a)*(/a+(#?a)*)*$

 ^ 
 a+
 (                    # (1 start)
      \#?
      a 
 )*                   # (1 end)
 (                    # (2 start)
      /
      a+
      (                    # (3 start)
           \#?
           a 
      )*                   # (3 end)
 )*                   # (2 end)
 $
```

*edit*: (Transposed from comment) If complexity is too high, some engines will not even compile it, some will silently fail at runtime, some will lock up in a backtracking loop.

This little subtle difference is the problem

bad:  too complex `(#?a+)*`
good: no nested, open ended quantifiers `(#?a)*`

If you ever have this problem, strip out the nesting, usually solves
the backtracking issue.

---

*eit2*: If you require a separator and want to insure a separator is only in the middle and surrounded by `a`'s, you could try this

https://play.golang.org/p/oM6B6H3Kdx

```
 #  ^a+[#/](a[#/]?)*a+$

 ^ 
 a+
 [\#/] 
 (                             # (1 start)
      a
      [\#/]? 

 )*                            # (1 end)
 a+
 $
```

or this

https://play.golang.org/p/WihqSjH_dI

```
 # ^a+(?:[#/]a+)+$

 ^ 
 a+ 
 (?:
      [\#/] 
      a+
 )+
 $
```

Comment: It works, but I cannot understand why the backtracking is important here. I assume that RE is just greedy, so in this case: ^1(2(_1+)*)*$" does not match "12_1" - ^1 eats 1, 2_1 left. (2...) eats 2, _1 left. (_1+)* eats _1. Empty, not bq. But it does not work this way.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: This little subtle difference is the problem `(\#?a)*` and `(\#?a+)*`

Comment: @sln hold on, we are still trying, but it is not simple. Apparently, RE2 does not do any of the above and it even tries to find the match. It works for "a", "a/a", "a#a/a", but not for "a/a#a". I'm reading through http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html and I cannot understand where backtracking happens in this case.

Comment: @AlexAtNet  - As you can see, the original regex was not correct, it matched `a` all by itself. A better one is probably needed.

Comment: what is also interesting,if take the first part in brackets(`^(a+(#a+)*)(/a+(#a+)*)*$`),the match will be correct. Why?

Comment: So for practical purposes the answer is that it is a bug in the engine and as a rule of thumb I should not use triple quantifier nesting to avoid hitting complexity bugs like that? Also, the suggested simplification should be `^a+[#/](a+[#/]?)*a+$ `, not `^a+[#/](a[#/]?)*a+$ `, which use 2-level nesting, not one

Comment: @IgorBukanov - Yeah, I think that when RE2 regex's end in _optional_ `*` nested quantifiers, it considers the complexity too high. In reality, you can reduce the regex to its bare minimum with this `^(?:a+[#/])+a+$` or `^a+(?:[#/]a+)+$`

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug in golang regexp engine. A simpler test case is that `^a(/a+(#a+)*)*$` fails to match `a/a#a` while `^(a)(/a+(#a+)*)*$` works, see http://play.golang.org/p/CDKxVeXW98 .

I filed https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11905